# Using Key Behavior Cache in scheduled task

Tags: xdb

I'm implementing a scheduled task that loops through contacts that have recently visited the site and sends over some analytics information to another service we have. The relevant parts of the code is

```
var contactRepository = new ContactRepository();
var contact = contactRepository.LoadContactReadOnly(contactId);
var keyBehaviorCache = contact.GetKeyBehaviorCache();
```

I'm getting an exception on the call to `GetKeyBehaviorCache()` that says contact.Attachments should contain key KeyBehaviorCache. Looking at the decompiled code, it's checking the contact for an attachment called KeyBehaviorCache that indeed doesn't exist on the contact.

```
Assert.IsTrue((contact.Attachments.ContainsKey("KeyBehaviorCache") ? 1 : 0) != 0, "contact.Attachments should contain key {0}", (object) "KeyBehaviorCache");
```

Looking at sitecore's documentation, I see that the key behavior cache isn't accessible during aggregating and reporting but only on a content delivery instance. That seems a little big vague to me. I'm currently running a single instance on my local machine.

Is this something that isn't possible to do from a scheduled task or has anyone done this successfully?

We're currently running version 8.2 (rev. 170728).

Comment: What type of data you need from the contact?

Comment: I'm trying to get the completed goals, triggered campaigns, engagement value, and any profile cards associated with the contact.

Comment: Please see answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the user is not in a session, you will need to load the contact behavior cache using the extension `LoadKeyBehaviorCache`. A code snippet is provided below.

```
public void GetContactInfo(string contactId)
{
    var contactGuid = Guid.Parse(contactId);

    var contactManager = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as ContactManager;

    var contact = contactManager.LoadContactReadOnly(contactGuid);

    contact.LoadKeyBehaviorCache();

    var behaviorCacheResults = contact.GetKeyBehaviorCache();

    //------------------------------------------------------//

    var historicalDataResults = contact.LoadHistorycalData(1).ToList();
}
```

Based on your comment on the question, you want to access

- completed goals
- triggered campaigns
- engagement value
- Any profile cards associated with the contact.

You will need to use both the Historical and Behavior Cache. Below is a classification of where you can obtain the data you require.

**Behavior Cache**

- completed goals
- triggered campaigns

**Historical Data**

- engagement value
- Any profile cards associated with the contact

### **Additional Information**

In the Behavior Cache, you can retrieve all the below data

```
Channels, Campaigns, Custom Values, Goals, Outcomes, Page Events, Venues
```

In the historical data, you can retrieve more information such as

```
SiteName, Pages, Referrer etc
```

You can dotpeek the `Sitecore.Analytics.dll` and navigate to the namespace `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.IInteractionData`. You will see all the properties that you can use to get additional information from the contact.